# Duplicate entry for key 'group_key'

Tags: mysql, key

I'm running a query in MySQL where I'm grouping by four columns and selecting a lot of things, including the four values I'm grouping by. But I get this error when I run the query:

```
Duplicate entry '92-0-10-7' for key 'group_key'
```

The 92, 0, 10, and 7 are all values of the four grouped-by columns for a particular row (actually, I checked, and there are 63 rows that fit those parameters). But I have no idea what that means, or how to run my query properly.

My query:

```
Create table table2 as
Select round(x, 0) as x, round(a, 0) as a, round(b, 0) as b, c, d, e, f
from table1
group by round(x, 0), round(a, 0), round(b, 0), c
```

The 92 would fit x, the 0 a, the 10 b, and the 7 c.

I have no indices on this table.

Thanks!

Comment: Your query is `SELECT` whereas that error message may only occur for DML (`UPDATE` or `INSERT`). So, the error message is caused by another query.

Comment: What do you mean another query? I'm only running this query and it still gives me that message. Also, FWIW, the actual query is a create table command, but the only difference is there is a "create table table2 as" in front of the select.

Comment: @zerkms I did try running the same query without the create table part and nothing changed, so I don't really think it matters.

Comment: well, `SELECT` query cannot cause that error

Comment: `GROUP BY` does not make sense in this query.  There is no aggregate function, here... `ROUND()` is not an aggregate function.  The values for d, e, and f cannot be properly determined.  Do you really mean `SELECT DISTINCT`?  Otherwise, is the purpose of the grouping?

Comment: May be a MySQL bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62755

Answer (score 15):

Your issue seems like a MySQL bug. I was reviewing the logs for our production server the other day and the error logs were filled with this error. I used the workaround below and the errors are gone.

> SET SESSION max_heap_table_size=536870912;
>
> SET SESSION tmp_table_size=536870912;

Source: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58081

Comment: worked for me too. mysql  5.6.33. Added these settings to my.cnf.

Comment: I can't really describe my table structure here, but using 5.6.35 and this didn't fix my error

Comment: You saved my bacon. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually disk space issue. Specially temporary space (in linux `/tmp`). Check you database server Disk space.

Comment: Changing MySQL's `tmpdir` to a folder with more free space solved this problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should put the alias names in the GROUP BY like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
SELECT ROUND(x, 0) AS x, ROUND(a, 0) AS a, ROUND(b, 0) AS b, c, d, e, f
FROM table1
GROUP BY x, a, b, c;
```