# MySQL Duplicate entry 'x' for key 'group_by'

Tags: mysql, group-by

This query:

```
SELECT count(*), floor(rand()*2) AS stuff FROM information_schema.tables GROUP BY stuff;
```

has strange behavior. About half the time it completes successfully with a result like this:

```
+----------+-------+
| count(*) | stuff |
+----------+-------+
|       41 |     0 |
|       45 |     1 |
+----------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

(The counts vary a bit.)

But the other half of the time it gives the error

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'group_key'
```

(Sometimes saying '0' instead of '1'.)

I'm not really interested in having any specific behavior happen. I would just like to understand what is going on.

I'm using MySQL version 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Comment: `SELECT` cannot cause this error, what else do you do?

Comment: That's the entire query. I'm just pasting it into the mysql console and it sometimes has that error.

Comment: It's not possible. That error can only be caused by DML query.

Comment: Did you try it? [This guy](https://youtu.be/zaRlcPbfX4M?t=16m22s) claims it was invented by a "team of intelligent researchers" for the purpose of aiding SQL injection.

Comment: Yep, it's reproducible. And seems like it's a mysql bug https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58081

Comment: That's cute!  Reproducible on a regular table, too.  (As opposed to something special happening with the pseudo-tables in `information_schema`.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate entry for key 'group\_key'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725772/duplicate-entry-for-key-group-key)