# SQL Double Query Injection

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query with me

```
select 
    count(*),
    concat((select database()), floor(rand() * 2)) as x        
from users 
group by x;
```

As I run this query in the MYSQL client over and over, I get 2 different responses. Sometimes, I end up with this error(which I expect as per the blog I am reading)

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'mobile10' for key 'group_key'
```

At other times, I get a result like :

```
+----------+------------------+
| count(*) | x                |
+----------+------------------+
|     6444 | mobile_app_dev10 |
|     6505 | mobile_app_dev11 |
+----------+------------------+
```

1. Why do I see 2 different results?
2. What exactly does the error in the first response mean?

Comment: How is this related to sql injection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicate entry for key 'group\_key'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725772/duplicate-entry-for-key-group-key)

Comment: @mikeTheLiar : I guess this one of the techniques used to get db data when SQL errors are exposed to the attacker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Double Query injection, the information can only be dumped via errors. When you used **floor(rand()*2)** function with **group by** clause it resulted in error not every time but when any duplicate entry occurs for group_key. Here, you forced an error to occur, though you randomized the inner query but again you used **floor()** to result duplicate entries as it results the nearest largest integer value of the number. OK. instead of **rand()*2** use **rand()*4** same error occurs when you execute the query but after many successful attempts of showing you the second result. the integer value of randomized data is now increased,now the chances of an error to occur are reduced comparatively. You can read more about Double Query [here](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/double-query-injections-demystified/).