# MYSQL query to find duplicate records based on first name and last name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a user table with following columns and i have come up with a query to identify the duplicate records based on the first name and last name.

table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `address1` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `mobile` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1 - female, 2-male, 0 - unknown',
  `zip` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `countryCode` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `joinedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateOfBirth` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'User date of birth'
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=63561 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and my query

```
SELECT id, firstName, lastName, mobile, email, count(*) as dupCount 
FROM `User` `t` 
WHERE firstName is not null and lastName is not null 
GROUP BY firstName,lastName HAVING count(*) > 1 
ORDER BY t.joinedDate DESC
```

below is the screenshot of the result when i run the query

[image]

and my data set is here http://pastebin.com/Y5qsTcFc

sorry if paste bin is not working. try this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3gG6MG9uh7KdmRGT3d0NWg2aVk/view?usp=sharing

when there are records with email address is NULL, we have a problem. i am always getting this error.

## 1062 - Duplicate entry 'Rachel-Besnainou' for key 'group_key'

[image]

Query i ran is:

```
SELECT id, firstName, lastName, mobile, email, count(*) as dupCount 
FROM `User` `t` 
WHERE firstName is not null and lastName is not null 
GROUP BY firstName,lastName 
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

I have no idea why this error comes up. any help appreciated

**Update 1**

i try to add this to my database and ran the query still it was the same

```
SET SESSION max_heap_table_size=536870912;

SET SESSION tmp_table_size=536870912;
```

ref: [Duplicate entry for key 'group_key'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725772/duplicate-entry-for-key-group-key)

**Update 2**

I tried the same database in diff mysql and phpmyadmin version and it worked. so looks like my mysql version has a bug. my mysql version is **5.6.26**

Comment: You set the pastebin to expire. Either remove the expiry or paste your code in the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry, i updated it from google drive. please see the question again

Comment: I think it isn't a good idea to post a full sql dump with Names + Emails

Comment: Your code with your data works for me on your mysql version. Might be a bug: [Duplicate entry for key 'group_key'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725772/duplicate-entry-for-key-group-key)

Comment: That `FROM User t` with the ticks around the `t` nags at me. If you're wanting to use that as an alias, you need to remove the ticks from around it, or just remove the `t` altogether. I've been staring at this for a while and for some reason, it just picks at me, I don't know why. @dev1234

Comment: @dev1234 You've been given a *"Try this"*. I've stayed here for as long as I could. You can ping me if you want. I've moved on now, good luck with this ;-)

Comment: have you try using ALTER IGNORE?

Comment: @kimdecastro no. if you can give an example? but please see i updated the question again. the same database worked fine in diff mysql version. looks like only solution is updating mysql version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select a1.id, 
a1.FirstName, 
a1.LastName,  
a1.mobile, 
a1.email
from user a1
inner join 
(
  select FirstName, LastName, count(id)
  from User
  where firstname is not null 
  and lastname is not null
  group by FirstName, LastName
  having count(id)>1
) u1
    on u1.FirstName = a1.Firstname
    and u1.Lastname = a1.lastname
order by a1.joineddate
```

Comment: This is the query i need. `select FirstName, LastName, count(id)
  from User
  where firstname is not null 
  and lastname is not null
  group by FirstName, LastName 
  having count(id)>1` and it gives the me the right data set.

Comment: And when i try get mobile no also with is `select FirstName, LastName, mobile, count(id) ` it gives me no error. but when i try get email with o mobile no like this, `select FirstName, LastName, count(id)
  from User
  where firstname is not null 
  and lastname is not null
  group by FirstName, LastName
  having count(id)>1` it still gives me the same error it was giving http://i.imgur.com/KqWkfsn.png