# MySQL query GROUP BY error - ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'hartz add on' for key 'group_key'

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have really big table in my mysql database from where I need to aggregate some data based on the specific field.

When I run following query, I get around 110000 results set.

`select count(*) from my_table where CampaignName LIKE 'My Campaign'`

I need to aggregate `profit` field based on `searchTerm` field for this campaign, so I tried to run following query.

`select sum(profit) from my_table where CampaignName LIKE 'My Campaign' group by searchTerm`

Then, I got following error.

`ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'hartz add on' for key 'group_key'`

I tried following from the answer for the similar question, but I get the same result.
([Duplicate entry for key 'group_key'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725772/duplicate-entry-for-key-group-key))

`SET SESSION max_heap_table_size=536870912;`

`SET SESSION tmp_table_size=536870912;`

I tried to set even 2GB for the tmp_table_size.

Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: It's a MySQL bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58081

Comment: Not to mention that in versions of MySQL past 5.5, group by used like this SHOULDN'T work.  You can only group by columns that are in the select clause of the query.  If searchterm is not a component of the select clause, the group by clause WILL find duplicates.  Particularly with a "like" in the where clause. Edit:  The bug was added in 2010 and never made it past triage because fixing it would be yet another non-standard SQL issue.