# Duplicate entry with Select MySQL - very strange

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have a very strange problem With a Select MySQL.

- MySQL Prod Server I have this error : #1062 - **Duplicata du champ '10250' pour la clef 'key0'** ( = # 1062 - Duplicate field '10250' for the key 'key0'). *MariaDB 10.0.28*.
- MySQL Dev Server, **I don't have error**. *MySQL 5.5*.
- This is a same database in Prod and Dev (Import Prod > Dev)

Here is the query. But, **I have simplified it a lot**. This is normal if it seems stupid to you, I simplified it to keep only the error :

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            IF(
                (
                    SELECT
                        SUBSTRING(ed2.numero2, 1, 1)
                    FROM
                        ecriture_detail ed2
                    WHERE
                        ed2.ecriture_id = ed1.ecriture_id
                    LIMIT
                        0, 1
                ) = 6,
                SUM(1),
                SUM(1)
            )
        FROM
            ecriture_detail ed1
            INNER JOIN
                compte s_c ON s_c.id = ed1.compte_id
            INNER JOIN
                association_detail s_ad ON s_ad.ecriture_detail_id = ed1.id
        WHERE
            ed1.compte_id = c.id
            AND ed1.ecriture_id = e.id
    ) AS amount,
    c.id AS c_order
FROM
    compte c
    INNER JOIN ecriture_detail ed ON
        c.id = ed.compte_id AND
        ed.date_suppression IS NULL
    INNER JOIN ecriture e ON
        ed.ecriture_id = e.id
    LEFT JOIN association_detail ad ON
        ad.ecriture_detail_id = ed.id
    LEFT JOIN association a ON
        a.id = ad.association_id
WHERE
    c.activite_id IN("66", "67", "68", "69", "144") AND
    SUBSTRING(c.numero, 1, 1) = "4" AND
    (
        a.complet != 1 
        OR a.complet IS NULL
    ) AND
    SUBSTRING(c.numero, 13, 6) != "000000"
HAVING
    amount != 0
ORDER BY
    c_order ASC
```

- If I remove "ORDER BY c_order ASC", **it's working**
- If I remove "HAVING amount != 0", **it's working**
- If I remove "(a.complet != 1 OR a.complet IS NULL)" in WHERE, **it's working**
- If I remove "INNER JOIN association_detail s_ad" in Subquery, **it's working**
- ***But the 4 together it does not work. But I do not see any link between all that***

Can you help me ?

Comment: This might be a bug, see [Duplicate entry for key 'group_key'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725772/duplicate-entry-for-key-group-key)

Answer (score 0):

Although this problem is documented as a bug (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58081) there is an interesting note in log for this bug:

> [16 Jul 2015 2:43] Yoseph Phillips
>
> I have seen this same error happen using MySQL 5.6.25 Here I worked at
>   that the cause was a corrupt index on a column used in the GROUP BY
>   clause (doing simple selects using that index would not return the
>   row, using other indexes would return the row).

So maybe check if some indexes are involved and if so you could try to reindex them.

Comment: The above-mentioned bug is not reproducible on any active versions of MariaDB, so it's not quite the same (could be a variation though). So, if you don't find the corruption mentioned in the answer, could you please report the bug at jira.mariadb.org? Please include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW INDEX IN` for the tables used in the query. If you can provide the data dump, it will be even better.

Comment: Thanks ; this solution it's not working : :(

"
SET SESSION max_heap_table_size=536870912; 
SET SESSION tmp_table_size=536870912;
"