# Got mysql group by error

Tags: mysql

I have such error: 
Duplicate entry 'earbuds+wireless+headphones' for key ''

Here is my query:

```
SELECT p.name FROM keywords as p
INNER JOIN keyword_product AS k ON p.id = k.keyword_id
GROUP BY p.name
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: On a _SELECT_ statement …? Hard to believe that. On an INSERT or UPDATE it would make sense, but SELECT ... nope.

Comment: That query doesn't correspond with the error you say you have

Comment: here is screenshot please http://joxi.ru/nAyb16XcXjO1dr   On local server works fine but on prod server I have that error, Production server use RDS Amazon

Comment: Can we see the data ? I think you have 2 same ids. Just let us see some data, this is awkward

Comment: both servers use the same DB dump

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate entry for key 'group\_key'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725772/duplicate-entry-for-key-group-key)

Comment: both tables dont have duplicated ids. My assumption - may be some mysql setting are wrong? I have that query working fine on localhost, only prod Rds Mysql drops such errors. Both server are using the same db.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, that helps, in my.cnf files add options:

```
max_heap_table_size=536870912
tmp_table_size=536870912
```